# Scout Eclipse RAP smart fields

Tags: drop-down-menu, updates, eclipse-scout, wab

I have problem with smart fields in RAP application in scout eclipse.

My problems are in Lookup calls, because on RAP (and only on RAP) sometimes does not update choices when user change search text. I refresh it when user click on search window or press up or down keys, but it is annoying.

When I debug it, I see that code is executed and new values are "returned" (In LookupService), but on there are no package come to browser.

Comment: which Scout and RAP version are you using? Are you able to share some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: We solve it. It seams that RAP stop listening to server if server took to long to calculate result. We extend time of listening to server and it works.